# communicationg to device using cdc usb protocol in c# windows application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, usb, serial-communication, cdc

I need help to create a c# application for usb communication using cdc protocol. My application is communicating to device by using by using usb communication protocol.Can somebody give me a sample application in c# showing sending and receiving of data using "Communication Device Class" usb protocol.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the SerialPort class, which is documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport

Comment: How to send data in packet of 64 bytes in serial port communication using c# rs232 protocol